# android Override a function in subclass

Tags: java, android

I make a class Figure then  two subclasses from it. Figure super class have a method named are(). this is the all class.

```
public class Figure
{
  public double a, b;
  public Figure(double a,double b) {
    this.a = a; 
    this.b = b;
  }

  public double are() {
    return 0;
  }
}

public class Rectangle extends Figure
{
  Rectangle(double a, double b) {
    super(a,b);
  }

  double area (){
    return this.a*this.b;
  }
}

class Triangle extends Figure
{
  Triangle(double a, double b) {
    super(a,b);
  }
  // override area for right triangle
  double area () {
    return a * b / 2;
  }
}
```

to easy print outpute I make

```
public  void toastM(String str) { 
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

now I use this code

```
 Figure f = new Figure(10, 10);
 Rectangle r = new Rectangle(9, 5);
 Triangle t = new Triangle(10, 8);

 Figure figref;
 figref = r;
 toastM("are.....   " + figref.are());
 figref = t;
 toastM("are.....   " + figref.are());
 figref = f;
 toastM("are.....   " + figref.are());
```

expected values are 45 40 0
but it come 0 0 0

Comment: parent class method name should be same as overriden in child class. see [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/method-overriding-in-java). Don't post questions without learning concepts properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent class has a method called

```
double are()
```

the child classes

```
double area()
```

so it's not overridden

Answer (score 0):

The functions you are overriding in both `Rectangle` and `Triangle` are called `area` AND NOT `are` as in the Figure class

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the are() function of the super class Figure, not the area() function the subclass.